# Fat and Saturated Fat

Tags: workout, nutrition, calories, health

When I buy a product, and it says like Nutrition per 100g is

```
Fat 100g
  Saturated 30g
```

When I count my calories then, should I write that the amount of fat is 70g and the saturated is 30g, so it totals to 100g

Or should it be 100g fat and an extra 30g saturated?

Thanks

Comment: Most applications and websites where you enter it in, you enter it just like the label. The first one is total fat and the second is the part that is saturated. If what you're using only asks for fat, just enter the first number. That said, we don't do nutrition questions here unless they directly apply to exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that there is 100g of fat total, and *out of that*, 30g is saturated.